# Finding Nash Equilibriums

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Nash Equilibrium for this Normal Game

`1,1  2,4  1,4`

`0,8  1,1  1,1`

`3,0  0,0  7,0`

I know for sure that the Nash Equilibrium : (2,4)
Is (3,0) and (7,0) also Nash Equilibriums?

Comment: What's the definition of a Nash equilibrium?

Comment: payoff where both players will not deviate, best payoff for the players

Comment: I think the definition is more like "best response" to what the other player is doing (although this is still not a formal definition) - there's no chance of finding a NE without having a clear idea of what a NE is.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if a point is a Nash Equilibrium, we see if a player will deviate given that the other player holds fixed. So consider $(3, 0)$. Suppose player one picks the bottom row. Will player two change columns? Player two will be no better off by doing such, but will also be no worse off. So $(3, 0)$ is a candidate for a Nash Equilibrium. Now suppose player two is fixed at column one. Clearly, player one won't change rows, as that would make him worse off. So $(3, 0)$ is a Nash Equilibrium.

The same analysis yields that $(7, 0)$ is also a Nash Equilibrium.